# Authentication modes of SMTP Server

Tags: smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I am developing a genric c# SMTP Client, that can pick up SMTP server from a configuration file and send an email.

Here I am facing an open point on how to cater the authentication needs of the server. Does c# SMTPCilent support only username-password mechanism or can it support other authentication  mechanism SMTP

Also does SMTP server use key/certificate based authentiation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your own SmtpClient, then it can implement any authentication mechanism(s) that you want.

SMTP itself doesn't define any authentication mechanisms. There is an AUTH extension which allows the server to advertize which SASL authentication mechanisms it supports.

For an example SmtpClient implementation that supports SASL AUTH, feel free to look at my SmtpClient implementation in [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).